# Finding last six digits of an exponential number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a number, let's say I have three numbers

```
const num1 = 21; // output: 21
const num2 = 12345678; // output: 345678
const num3 = 1.359801885649216e+34; // output: ?? (probably 000000)
```

Should point out that I don't really know what `e+` does

I need to find the last six digits (or the available amount) of any of these numbers.

How would I be able to find the last six digits of these numbers in Javascript?

Comment: They are zeroes. Or did you want '16e+34'. Please, be more specific.

Comment: last 6 digits before decimal?

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific. @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: What is the expected output for `num3`?

Comment: please add the value of *??*

Comment: not specific enough.  In floating point math, 1.359801885649216e+34 is _approximately_ equal to 13598018856492160000000000000000000, but not exactly, because a 64 bit double can't actually hold that specific value.

Comment: In the case of integers just do `n % 1000000`. In the case of decimal you didn't specify.

Comment: Also "probably"?? Are we supposed to guess at random??

Comment: Something like `num.toPrecision(100).split(".")[0].slice(-6)`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca `(1.359801885649216e+34) % 1000000 === 441024`, because of the accuracy issue I mentioned before.   Without the issue the answer _should_ be zero.

Comment: @Alnitak I specified "in the case of integers". Unless you mean to clarify that "probably" in the question, in which case I still don't understand what OP means.

Comment: I think it would be valuable if you specified the "real life" problem you're trying to solve with this code, in order to understand exactly why this is needed and what the expected outcome is. A clear definition of requirements is the first step, always.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca in a strictly mathematical sense 1.359801885649216e+34 _is_ an integer.   Unfortunately floating point math means that the closest representable value is 13598018856492160349090412205441024.

Comment: @iremlopsum what's the _real_ problem you're trying to solve?   If you think you need the last 6 digits of a 35 digit number you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a rest of `1e6`, but you get only the closest value of the floating point number, as *Alnitak* points out in the comments.

For the last case, the number

```
13598018856492160349090412205441024
```

is taken and the last 6 digits are

```
                             441024
```

```js
console.log([21, 12345678, 1.359801885649216e+34].map(v => v % 1e6));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find the last six digits (or the available amount) of any of
>   these numbers.

I am assuming that you meant - **last 6 digits before decimal**

Use [toPrecision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision) with maximum precision `100`

```
num = 1.359801885649216e+34;
var fnLastNDigits = ( num, N ) => num.toPrecision( 100 ).split( "." )[ 0 ].slice( -N );

console.log( fnLastNDigits( num )  );
```

**Explanation**

- `num.toPrecision( 100 )` returns string value with given precision
- `split( "." )[0]` splits the value by `.` and return the first value of array
- `slice(-N)` gets the last N digits